# Why can't find com.apple.nsurlsessiond folder in iOS 10?

Tags: nsurlsession

When I update Xcode 7 to Xcode 8, I cannot find the folder `com.apple.nsurlsessiond` in caches. First in iOS 9, I can download and resume, but in iOS 10, I can't resume. Why so? I have print the log:

> Invalid resume data for background download. Background downloads must use http or https and must download to an accessible file.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLSession resume is broken in iOS10 - https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/180964#180964

You can find your temp download files now in NSTemporaryDirectory()